# IMemorycache keep calling sql on server

Tags: .net, caching, .net-core, memorycache

Below code works as expected on localhost, basically i check for cache key if exist it returns the value, if its not, it gets the value from database then i set 2 cache keys, if main cache expires i return backup key and start a task which sets the main cache again, purpose of this action is i dont want to wait for database call after cache expired instead i return backup key and set main key again.
Problem is , this code works on local machine and in debug mode it returns the cache after setting it, code doesnt call sql if its in cache, but on server it seems like memorycache is failing because on ssms i check for last executed queries and whenever i need this data it runs the query again. In debug mode it doesnt run the query again. Whats wrong with this, environment is .net core 2.2.

```
public async Task<MenuList> GetMenus()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_cache.TryGetValue(_menusCacheKey, out MenuList menus))
            {
                return menus;
            }
            else
            {
                if (_cache.TryGetValue(_menusBackupCacheKey,
                    out MenuList _menusBackup))
                {
                    new Task(() =>
                    {
                        var getMenus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ViewModels.Menu.Menu>>(_apiClient.Post(_appSettings.Api.Endpoints.GetMenus, 1).Result);
                        var menuItemPerCol = (int)GetSettings("MenuItemPerCol");

                        var model = new MenuList();
                        model.Menus = getMenus;
                        model.MenuItemPerCol = menuItemPerCol;

                        _cache.Set(_menusCacheKey, model,_menuCacheExpiration);
                        _cache.Set(_menusBackupCacheKey, model);
                    }).Start();

                    return _menusBackup;
                }

                var getMenusG = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ViewModels.Menu.Menu>>(await _apiClient.Post(_appSettings.Api.Endpoints.GetMenus, 1));
                var menuItemPerColG = (int)GetSettings("MenuItemPerCol");

                var modelG = new MenuList();
                modelG.Menus = getMenusG;
                modelG.MenuItemPerCol = menuItemPerColG;

                _cache.Set(_menusBackupCacheKey, modelG);

                return _cache.Set(_menusCacheKey, modelG, _menuCacheExpiration);
            }
        }
```

Here is my MenuList class ;

```
public class MenuList
{

    public MenuList()
    {
        Menus = new List<Menu>();
    }
    public List<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
    public int MenuItemPerCol { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this that does not require you doing any extra work would be to use [FusionCache ⚡](https://github.com/jodydonetti/ZiggyCreatures.FusionCache), a library I recently released.

It has what you are looking for, thanks to the combo of 2 features: [fail-safe](https://github.com/jodydonetti/ZiggyCreatures.FusionCache/blob/main/docs/FailSafe.md) + [advanced timeouts](https://github.com/jodydonetti/ZiggyCreatures.FusionCache/blob/main/docs/Timeouts.md) with background factory completion.

In short: you can cache something for, let's say, 2 min after which a factory would be called to refresh the data but, in case of problems (exceptions, timeouts, etc), that expired value would be used again until the factory is able to complete in the background, after which it will update the cache right away.

This is a sample call:

```cs
public async Task<MenuList> GetMenusAsync()
{
    return await fusionCache.GetOrSetAsync(
        _menusCacheKey,
        _ => async {
            var getMenus = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ViewModels.Menu.Menu>>(_apiClient.Post(_appSettings.Api.Endpoints.GetMenus, 1).Result);
            var menuItemPerCol = (int)GetSettings("MenuItemPerCol");
            
            var model = new MenuList();
            model.Menus = getMenus;
            model.MenuItemPerCol = menuItemPerCol;
            
            return model;
        },
        options => options
            .SetDuration(_menuCacheExpiration)
            .SetFailSafe(true, TimeSpan.FromHours(2))
            .SetFactoryTimeouts(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
    );
}
```

FusionCache also has other features you may find interesting, like an optimization that avoids [multiple concurrent factory calls](https://github.com/jodydonetti/ZiggyCreatures.FusionCache/blob/main/docs/FactoryOptimization.md) at the same time for the same key (useful when multiple threads try to access the same cache entry at the same time).

Another interesting feature is support for an optional, distributed [2nd level](https://github.com/jodydonetti/ZiggyCreatures.FusionCache/blob/main/docs/CacheLevels.md) cache, automatically managed and kept in sync with the local one for you without doing anything.

If you will give it a chance please let me knowwhat you think.

/shameless-plug